# Quelle est la meilleure formulation ci-après ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions, formulation, reformulation

1- Je vais me renseigner sur le temps qu’il fera à Toronto demain/qu’il fera demain à Toronto.

2- Je vais me renseigner sur les prévisions météorologiques pour Toronto demain.

L’action de se renseigner a lieu immédiatement après que l’agent a écrit l’une de ces phrases par messagerie et non pas le jour suivant cet échange. Il est question du temps qu’il fera demain (le lendemain de cette conversation) à Toronto. Est-ce qu’il serait préférable d’accompagner le verbe « renseigner » d’un adverbe de temps comme « maintenant » pour lever l’ambiguïté possible ?

Je vais me renseigner maintenant sur le temps qu’il fera à Toronto demain.

Je vais me renseigner maintenant sur les prévisions météorologiques pour Toronto demain.

Je suis ouvert aux reformulations !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I**

1a- *Je vais me renseigner sur le temps qu’il fera à Toronto demain.*

Cette construction est ambigüe, on ne sait pas très bien si on va se renseigner demain ou s'il s'agit du temps demain à Toronto. Elle peut convenir lorsque l'interlocuteur est parfaitement conscient que ce qui est en question c'est le temps qu'il fera demain.

1b- *Je vais me renseigner sur le temps qu’il fera demain à Toronto.*

Cette phrase-ci est sans ambigüité.

2- *Je vais me renseigner sur les prévisions météorologiques pour Toronto demain.*

On peut faire les mêmes remarques que pour « 1a ». La phrase suivante est sans ambigüité.

- Je vais me renseigner sur les prévisions météorologiques pour demain concernant Toronto.

**II**

**A**

Comme je perçois un certain intérêt pour une discussion discriminatrice à propos de plusieurs choix possibles de préposition, j'ajoute certaines indications.

**Pourquoi pas « à propos de » ou « au sujet de » au lieu de « pour » ou « concernant », « à propos » signifiant « au sujet », « en ce qui concerne » ?**

Une chose est sûre, si on examine les synonymes tels que proposés par le [Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C3%A0_propos_de), c'est à dire « *au sujet de, concernant, quant à, pour ce qui est de, s’agissant de* » (on pourrait ajouter « en ce qui concerne, relatif à »), on peut dire sans erreur que « *quant à, pour ce qui est de, s’agissant de* » ne sont pas des synonymes exact dans le contexte présent et ne conviennent pas ; quant aux autres (*à propos de, au sujet de, s’agissant de, en ce qui concerne, relatif à* »), je leur trouve quelque chose d'inapproprié qui m'empêcherais probablement de les utiliser dans ce contexte, mais qui reste indéfinissable selon mes conceptions, de sorte que je ne peux pas les déconseiller.

**Pourquoi pas « sur Toronto (pour) demain » ?**

Cette préposition dans le présent contexte pourrait être très particulière au français métropolitain et un canadien pourrait ne pas la trouver assez familière. Elle est cependant acceptable dans le français de France.

([réf., 2010](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Sang_d_encre_au_36/FBWh9UBzZp4C?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22temps+sur+paris%22&pg=PT50&printsec=frontcover)) En quelques jours, le temps sur Paris s'était dégradé. Le nuage laiteux couvrant la Seine au petit matin avait laissé place à une pluie continue et violente ...

**Pourquoi pas « de Toronto (pour) demain » ?**

Il y a d'abord le fait que même  pour une ville très importante comme Paris, on ne trouve pas « météo de Paris » ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=m%C3%A9t%C3%A9o+de+Paris&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=30&smoothing=3&direct_url=)) ; ça semble être une construction assez vague. Néanmoins on peut trouver des références comme la suivante;

([réf.](https://books.google.fr/books?id=AF8EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA11&dq=%22m%C3%A9t%C3%A9o+de+france%22&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYy6mIr67yAhVBRBoKHWPNA5kQ6AEwBHoECCsQAg#v=onepage&q=%22m%C3%A9t%C3%A9o%20de%20france%22&f=false)) Le site fournit la météo de France, du monde, de la montagne et des plages avec des prévisions à trois jours sous forme de deux pictogrammes à […]

Alors, pourquoi pas « la météo de Paris » ? Donc, la météo(rologie) de Toronto » est, à la limite, acceptable ; mais ce n'est pas une construction empreinte de beaucoup de spécificité ; dans ce context particulier on peut l'interpréter comme « la météo qui est fournit par Paris », où « Paris », par métonymie devient l'organisme parisien chargé de prévisions météorologiques ou bien la station de radio établie à Paris qui diffuse ces prévisions ; il existe aussi de nombreux cas de « météo de France 2 » et « météo de France Inter », et il s'agit évidemment des prévisions diffusées par ces organismes. Donc, comme on vient de le voir « de » n'est pas bien spécifique dans ce contexte, mais il est utilisable.

**B**

3- Je vais me renseigner maintenant sur le temps qu’il fera à Toronto demain.

« Maintenant » convient parfaitement ; il est habituel d'utiliser « maintenant » dans des oppositions (bien que je n'arrive pas à situer dans le dictionnaire l'opposition particulière dont il est question, j'en suis parfaitement conscient ; voir le [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/maintenant), peut-être trouverez-vous quelque chose qui m'a échappé ;  donc, l'opposition est entre le moment que le locuteur avait déterminé dans le futur et le présent (qui peut être plus ou moins le future proche et non nécessairement ce qui correspond à « sur le champs ») (Je vais le faire maintenant, pas demain). Dans ce présent contexte d'une rectification du moment où l'action prend place, « demain » à la fin de la phrase n'est plus un problème ; cependant, un meilleur style serait celui de la phrase suivante.

- 3'- Je vais me renseigner maintenant sur le temps qu’il fera demain à Toronto.

4- Je vais me renseigner maintenant sur les prévisions météorologiques pour Toronto demain.

C'est une construction qui me semble acceptable. Néanmoins, le groupe prépositionnel « sur les prévisions météorologiques pour Toronto demain » semble comporter une certaine imprécision, et donc, paraitre un peu lourd. Bien qu'il y ait peu de chances qu'il s'agisse des prévisions météorologique faites demain pour Toronto, la formulation n'écarte pas cette possibilité, d'où une inhérente ambigüité qui pourrait être considérée comme préjudiciable au style.

On peut alors peut-être préférer la construction suivante.

- 4'- Je vais me renseigner maintenant sur les prévisions météorologiques pour Toronto pour demain. (*ou « pour demain pou Toronto »*)

(*ou si on veut éliminer la répétition de « pour »*)

- 4''- Je vais me renseigner maintenant sur les prévisions météorologiques  pour demain concernant Toronto.

Answer (score 0):

Les deux premières phrases sont toutes deux convenables. Si tu veux insister sur le fait que l'action sera immédiate, tu peux utiliser le présent. Je trouve aussi que *tout de suite* me semble plus naturel que *maintenant* dans ce cas :

> Je me renseigne tout de suite sur les prévisions météo de Toronto pour demain.

> Je regarde tout de suite quelles sont les prévisions météo pour Toronto demain.

Comment: Les choix abondent « pour Toronto demain », « de Toronto pour demain », et pourquoi pas « de Toronto demain »…